# What could be causing redux state load delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple placeholder component that just displays a loading screen. But in the background, it's making checks to be redirected to the correct path. Using react-redux I can select a property in my state.

```
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          history.push("/home");
        } else {
          history.push("/login");
        }
      }, [isAuthenticated, history]);

   return (
       <Spin size="large" />
   );
```

//Redux store config

```
const configureStore = (persistedState) => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    persistedState,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
  );
  store.dispatch(validateAuth());
  return store;
};
```

But when I check the console the output below shows it might be loading the initial state then the updated state. What could be causing this delay? As it is always redirecting to /login

[image]

Comment: Can you just wait until the Redux state is loaded to mount your route component? Without more details of your implementation, I fear your question may be impossible to answer. Blind speculation could save the day, but it's unlikely.

Comment: My guess is that `isAuthenticated` is set by an asynchronous action (you can check redux devtools). If this is the case you also need an `isAuthenticatedLoading` to indicate that it is currently checking if user is authenticated so `isAuthenticated` is not determined yet. A timeout won't do the trick because a slow connection will set authenticated after the timeout and you create a race condition that can fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        console.log("I'm here")
      } else {
        history.push("/login");
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [isAuthenticated, history]);
```

I decided to wrap my useEffect action in a timeout to wait for the correct state to be loaded. If this is incorrect or not the best practice please let me know a better answer.